# python does not return anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop

Here's the instruction:

Define a function named  giveMeRemainPos(...)  which receives one string (st) and one character (ch) and returns a new string containing the remainder of dividing by 3 the position  where the character is found, each remainder separated by two dots (and at the start and end of the string to be returned there should also be two dots).   If the character ch  is  the not present in the original string then the function should return a string containing only two dots.
For example,

s = "abcdabcdabcdabcd"
c = "a"
giveMeRemainPos(s,c)

will  cause the function to return the string '..0..1..2..0..' because  "a" is in positions  0,4,8,12  and respectively, the remainders of dividing such positions by 3 will produce the values 0,1,2,0.

```
def giveMeRemainPos(s,c):
    res=".."
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if (s[i]==c):
            res=res+str(i%3)+".."
    return res
s = "abcdabcdabcdabcd"
c = "a"
giveMeRemainPos(s,c)
```

The output should be this:

```
..0..1..2..0..
```

But my code returns me nothing at all. Even if I return a random string like`return "astring"`.

Comment: What makes you think it's not returning anything? Obviously it's not going to print anything, because you're not printing anything.

Comment: Is it a mistake that you don't store or use the returned value of the function call?

Comment: Works in interactive, because it displays the result of the function call. I think you just need to `print` the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the result to display you have to use print 
If you want to use the result you have to assign it to a variable (eg x= giveMeRemainPos(s, c)

Comment: Oh! I thought there's something wrong with my code! Thank you so much!

Comment: With pleasure. If this solved your problem please validate my answer :)